# Pandas Divide two data-frames based on similar keys

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a df with values as:

```
user_id  sub_id   score
39       16       1
39       4        1
40       1        3
40       2        3
40       3        3
```

and

```
user_id score
39      2
40      30
```

So I want to divide columns based on key *user_id*, such that my result should be as:

```
user_id  sub_id   score
39       16       0.5
39       4        0.5
40       1        0.1
40       2        0.1
40       3        0.1
```

I have tried the *div* operation but it is not working as per my need, It is only dividing the first appearance and giving me *NAN* for else.

Is there any direct pandas operation or do I need to group both df's and then do the division? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) by `Series` created by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['score'] = df1['score'].div(df1['user_id'].map(df2.set_index('user_id')['score']))
print (df1)
   user_id  sub_id  score
0       39      16    0.5
1       39       4    0.5
2       40       1    0.1
3       40       2    0.1
4       40       3    0.1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1['user_id'].map(df2.set_index('user_id')['score']))
0     2
1     2
2    30
3    30
4    30
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @NikhilVerma - Glad can help!